# Swipe between images with scroll view indicator in the bottom

Tags: android

My aim to implement scroll view between the images along with the indicator in the bottom. Please refer the image below.

[image]

I have already Implemented view flipper to swipe between images , but how to implement the indicator in the bottom to make user indentify that it is a scroll view.

Thanks.

Comment: You will use viewpager to swipe images and to chnage circles at bottom you can use addOnPageChangeListener on viewpager

Comment: Thanks. It would be very helpful if you please provide some example link or code.

Comment: try to this link  http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: search google.There are lot of tutorials on viewpager and addOnPageChangeListener